# How to populate same value for multiple rows using pl/sql

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql

How do I populate the same data into multiple rows, if the employee `id` is the same. Without querying the table every time
E.g.
If I get below rows from the Employee Table

```
EMPLID  CHANGETIME
------  --------------
1234    8/10/2017
1234    8/11/2017
```

For the above employee I need to query the NAME table to get the names and populate both rows.

```
EMPLID  CHANGETIME  FirstNAME LastNAME
------  ----------  --------- --------
1234    08/10/17    JOHN       MATHEW
1234    08/11/17    JOHN       MATHEW
```

When I query first time would like to store it in array or some variable and populate the same if EMPLID matches previous one.

Just want to do this to improve performance. Any hint would be helpful.

Right now I'm using bulk insert into type table and it goes and searches the NAME table every time a row is fetched from EMPLOYEE table

Answer (score 0):

I would use a join for getting the employee name (also within pl/sql) like:

    `SELECT e.emplid, e.first_name, e.last_name, c.changetime
    FROM employee_changes c
    INNER JOIN employee e ON e.emplid = c.emplid
    WHERE c.change_time > sysdate - 30
    ORDER BY e.emplid, c.change_time`

Select can be used as cursor if you want to ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some extra criteria, like "the last change time".
In that case you can code something like this:

```
SELECT e.EMPLID, e.CHANGETIME, n.FirstNAME, n.LastNAME
  FROM Employee e, NAME n
 WHERE e.emplid = n.emplid
   AND e.changetime = (SELECT MAX(e1.changetime)
                         FROM Employee e1
                        WHERE e1.emplid = e.emplid);
```

"For each Employee, just get de max changetime"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 11g you should consider using the Result Cache feature. This allows us to define functions whose returned values are stored in memory. Something like this:

```
create or replace function get_name 
    (p_empid pls_integer)
    return varchar2
    result_cache relies_on (names)
is
  return_value varchar2(30);
begin
    select empname into return_value  
    from names
    where empid = p_empid;
    return return_value;
end get_name;
/
```

Note the RELIES_ON clause: this is option but it makes the point that caching is only useful for slowly changing tables. If there's a lot of churn in the NAMES table Oracle will keep flushing the cache and you won't get much benefit. But at least the results will be correct - something which you can't guarantee with your current approach.

Here is a sample. Ignore the elapsed times, but mark how little effort is required to get the same employee name on the second call:

```
SQL> set autotrace on 
SQL> set timing on
SQL> select get_name(7934) from dual
  2  /

GET_NAME(7934)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MILLER

Elapsed: 00:00:01.25

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1388734953

-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  FAST DUAL       |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
        842  recursive calls
        166  db block gets
       1074  consistent gets
         44  physical reads
      30616  redo size
        499  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        437  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
        134  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed

SQL>
```

Second call:

```
SQL> r
  1* select get_name(7934) from dual

GET_NAME(7934)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MILLER

Elapsed: 00:00:00.13

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1388734953

-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  FAST DUAL       |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------    

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          0  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        499  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        437  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed

SQL>
```

The documentation has lots on this nifty feature. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00817).